# Get list of files in Cloud Storage (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there any possibility to list all files on my Google Cloud Storage bucket with the GAE SDK? I know that the Python SDK supports such a function, but I can't find a similar function in the Java SDK.

If not available, will this be added in the future releases of the Java SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Cloud Storage JSON API via its [client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Cloud_Storage_API). Once you set up your credentials you can make the call like this:

```
Storage storage = new Storage(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential);
ObjectsList list = storage.objects().list("bucket-name").execute();
for (Object obj : list.getItems()) {
  //...
}
```

You may want to use an `AppIdentityCredential` in this case as well, which will allow the bucket to be owned by your application, and not by a user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. I thought i could use such a functionality without another library :( . But its ok, maybe they integrate these functions at any time later.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this using the [Google Java Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) (which is replacing the [Google Cloud Storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/))

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

ListResult result = gcsService.list(appIdentity.getDefaultGcsBucketName(), ListOptions.DEFAULT);
while (result.hasNext()){
    ListItem l = result.next();
    String name = l.getName();

    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
}
```

If you only want to iterate through a certain "directory", use the ListOptions builder

```
ListOptions.Builder b = new ListOptions.Builder();
b.setRecursive(true);
b.setPrefix("directory");
...

ListResult result = gcsService.list(appIdentity.getDefaultGcsBucketName(), b.build());
...
```