# how to get multiple files from cloud storage to big query using java api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have data in the cloud storage and I want to transfer the data to big query and get statistics.
currently I'm using a JobConfigurationLoad to get a single file here is a sample of the code:

```
JobConfigurationLoad jobconfigurationqLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();
jobconfigurationqLoad.setSkipLeadingRows(1); // First line are columns names
    jobconfigurationqLoad.setSourceUris(Lists.newArrayList("gs://my_app/folder_name/test_file.csv"));
jobconfigurationqLoad.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
jobconfigurationqLoad.setEncoding(PlatformConstants.DEFAULT_ENCODING);
jobconfigurationqLoad.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
jobconfigurationqLoad.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
**tableReference = my table in big query
jobconfigurationqLoad.setSchemaInline("field1:STRING,field2:STRING");

// JobConfiguration
JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = new JobConfiguration();
jobConfiguration.setLoad(jobconfigurationqLoad);

// JobReference
JobReference jobreference = new JobReference();
jobreference.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);

// Job
Job insertJob = new Job();
insertJob.setConfiguration(jobConfiguration);
insertJob.setJobReference(jobreference);
```

In "setSourceUris" I wanted to put only the folder and get all the files that are there but that doesn't seems to work.
I saw it the google api some doc about getting a bucket content but not only one folder inside the bucket.
something similar is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418076/get-list-of-files-in-cloud-storage-java).
i'm using GAE with java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery Apis has property: configuration.load.sourceUris[]
which is an array that can contain one or more file.
the names must be "fully-qualified names, for example: gs://mybucket/myobject.csv"

for more info , take a look at:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs

so, as Michael said:
" use the Google Cloud Storage API to [provide a list of object URIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list). Provide a prefix parameter to filter the result list."

and then place the file names in the sourceUris array of your job.

Answer (score 2):

The BigQuery API's [sourceUris](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#importing) method requires that you list each source URI separately (it's not possible to provide a single Google Cloud Storage bucket URI).

However, yes you can use the Google Cloud Storage API to [provide a list of object URIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list). Provide a `prefix` parameter to filter the result list.

Note that the maximum amount of files you can include in a single load job is 500 (and the maximum amount of data per single load request is 1Tb - see the [BigQuery quota page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#import)).

Comment: you are right , except for the first part. see my answer. thanks anyway, your answer did help me .